# Should show all the series name on hover to the point which is crossing to that point in line chart (Highcharts)

Tags: angular, highcharts, linechart

I am facing one issue while using line chart. some series of chart is crossing to same point and on hover I am only able to show last one series. I want to show all the series name so that user can understand that which series is crossing to that point.

HTML:

```
<highcharts-chart [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [options]="chartOptions" [oneToOne]="true"[(update)]="gotScorecardData" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block;"></highcharts-chart>
```

ts:

```
this.chartOptions = {
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: true
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
      return `<div><b>Scorecard name: </b>${this.series.name}<br><b>Score: </b>`+Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.y,3)+`<br><b>Performance period: </b>${this.point.category}</div>`;
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Score',
      style: {
        fontSize: '12px',
        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
        color: '#485465'
      }
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    labels: {
      rotation: 0,
      style: {
        fontSize: '10px',
        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
        color: '#485465'
      },
    },
    categories: this.dateHeaderArray
  },
  series: this.seriesDataArray
};
```

sample data which we are passing in this.seriesDataArray:

```
[
    {
        "name": "a_c5af-4825-86df-bc5_f358-4520-a876-942",
        "type": "line",
        "data": [
            null,
            null,
            null,
            {
                "month": 4,
                "year": 2022,
                "y": 100,
                "className": "scorecard-graph-point"
            },
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
        ],
        "point": {
            "events": {}
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "a_c5af-4825-86df-bc5_bd76-45c1-ad20-0b0",
        "type": "line",
        "data": [
            null,
            null,
            null,
            {
                "month": 4,
                "year": 2022,
                "y": 100,
                "className": "scorecard-graph-point"
            },
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
        ],
        "point": {
            "events": {}
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "a_c5af-4825-86df-bc5_17e9-4094-8444-d17",
        "type": "line",
        "data": [
            null,
            null,
            null,
            {
                "month": 4,
                "year": 2022,
                "y": 100,
                "className": "scorecard-graph-point"
            },
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
        ],
        "point": {
            "events": {}
        }
    },   
]
```

final output:

[image: Final Output]

series name is getting overwritten with latest series and only last series name is being displayd but I need to display all the series name on hover.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can use `tooltip.shared` or `tooltip.split` options to show the tooltip for the few, same value&category points.

API References:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.shared
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.split

But in your example, if only want to add all crossing points series to the tooltip, you need to modify your formatter function:

```
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      let hoveredPoint = this,
       s = '';

      hoveredPoint.series.chart.series.forEach(series => {
        if (series._i != hoveredPoint.series._i) {
          series.points.forEach(point => {
            if (point.category === hoveredPoint.key && point.y === hoveredPoint.y) {
              s += `${point.series.name}, `;
            }
          })
        } else {
          s += `${hoveredPoint.series.name}<br>`;
        }
      })

      return `<b>Scorecard name: </b>` + s + `<b>Score: </b>` + Highcharts.numberFormat(hoveredPoint.point.y, 3) + `<br><b>Performance period: </b>${hoveredPoint.point.category}</div>`;
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cg0orfbL/